# No puedo ingresar a mi archivo .js desde mi archivo .html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente estoy usando un pequeño plugin para embellecer mi select dentro de mi html, el problema es que me marca el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).niceSelect is not a function`, intente meter un `console.log();` y un `alert();` dentro del archivo externo de .js que agregue a mi proyecto, borre los coockies y le di en recargar pero no se vio ningun cambio ni aparecio el alert que habia puesto, lo puse en diferentes ubicaciones y tengo entendido que el error que me sale actualmente hace referencia a que mi metodo no esta declarado, si esta declarado solo que no entra al archivo

Archivo externo

```
<script src="nice.js"></script>
```

Codigo para iniciar el select

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').niceSelect();
});

</script>
```

Esta es la imagen de como esta estructurado mi proyecto, el nombre de mi archivo que estoy llamando no esta incorrecto y la ruta tampoco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error lo marca aquí `$('select').niceSelect();`

Error completo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 3 preguntas :Primero tienes la libreria JQuery? como la estas llamando? Tienes el plugin de niceSelect

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores Si tengo jquery por medio de su cdn   (<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>).    Si tengo el plugin (<script src="nice.js"></script>)

Comment: pon el codigo des tu html tal vez lo estas llamndo antes de llamar al jquery eso ase q te salga el error

Comment: Debes de incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Asegúrate de llamar los .js en el orden correcto: primero jquery y luego nice.
- Esos dos scripts ubícalos en la parte de abajo, antes de cerrar el body .

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. En cuanto tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Mejor es proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores: Discrepo en cuanto a que esta publicación no sea una respuesta. Si es una respuesta, el que sea buena o mala es otra cosa.

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores al no haber publicado su html para ver en donde estaba ubicando sus scripts, en vez de pedirle que lo suba, sugerí una revisión de lo que podría causar el problema lo que parece haber sido útil. Saludos.